# Creating console app interface and calling in Xamarin PCL project

Tags: .net, xamarin, console-application, iot

I am creating a console app in .Net for Azzure IoT that refers in Xamarin cross platform. So what should be approach to achieve it?

Referencing console app in xamarin cross platform doesn't work. I tried creating console project in xamarin and referring in PCL project.

Should I create interface for console app? Is it possible? Or suggest me other ways to do so.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface that exposes the methods you want to be able call of your console project on the pcl project. The interface should be defined on the pcl project, you must have a property where you will set the instance that implements this interface on your pcl project. On the console project you will implement the interface and assign the pcl exposed property to an instance of this implementation.

Other option is using a shared project instead of pcl you will be able to call it directly from your common project.

Comment: Thanks.. thats what i was thinking about.. I have an old PCL project so cannot create new shared project for. Will try to interfacing console app

Comment: I am getting issue while implementing interface. Can you see it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658302/getting-null-exception-while-implementing-interface-in-xamarin